# Mingw - kernel32.mod - No such file or directory

Tags: module, compiler-errors, fortran, mingw, kernel32

I would like to compile a program with MinGW that is written in Fortran and that comes with a .dll. In the Fortran code there is the following line:

```
USE kernel32
```

When I try to compile it, it always says that the kernel32.mod can not be opened. No such file and directory. I am not sure what to do. Are there just some compiler options missing or is it simply not possible to compile it with MinGW?

(Windows 7, MinGW 3.20)

Comment: My guess would be that you forgot to set the `include` directory (`-I/path/to/module/files`)!

Comment: In the whole MinGW directory is no kernel32.mod. Only a libkernel32.a.

Comment: Then you probably need to locate/download `kernel32.f90` & compile it for your code to work.

Comment: Doing some research online it seems like this file is compiler specific. So if it is not included in MinGW then MinGW is probably not the right tool for such compilations. Does anyone here has some experience with such a situation. What tools do you use?

Comment: If you just have the library, but not the module, you can write explicit `interface`s for the required `subroutine`(s) and `function`(s) instead of `use`ing the module.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the module from the Intel (and ancestors) family of Fortran compilers that provides Fortran definitions for things corresponding to the kernel32.lib import library (for the kernel32.dll Windows system dynamic link library) and the appropriate parts of the Windows.h header file.

You may be able to identify the things from the module that are being used by your code, and provide your own definitions.  For procedures and types this will almost certainly require the use of compiler extensions to specify things like calling convention and alignment that is consistent with the convention and alignment used by the Windows system DLLs.  This conventions vary between 32 bit and 64 bit Windows platforms.